# Call function method from generic type if all types have the same function

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have a function that has a generic parameter

The generic passed will be two WCF DataContracts that each have the same method function

```
    [DataContract]
    public class FirstPayload
    {
        public string getProperty()
        {
            return "1";
        }
    }
```

and

```
    [DataContract]
    public class SecondPayload
    {
        public string getProperty()
        {
            return "2";
        }
    }
```

```
private void MyFunction(T myPayload)
{
    // What I want
    //how do I call the method getProperty from the generic parameter myPayload?
    string currLoad = myPayload.getProperty();

    // Less Ideal: have to make logic for each different type.
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(FirstPayload)) // long and have to repeat code for each different object
    {
        FirstPayload firstPayload = (FirstPayload)(object)myPayload;
        string currLoad = firstPayload.getProperty();
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can call the **getProperty** method from the parameter **myPayload** succintly? I know I can first check the typeof(myPayload) and then create an object based out of myPayload and then call the method but that can get tedious and repetitive. How can I do this optimally knowing that each object will have the same getProperty function?

Edit: Based upon feedback created interface

```
    public interface IGetProperty
    {
        string getProperty();
    }
```

```
    [DataContract]
    public class FirstPayload<T> where T: IGetProperty
    {
        public string getProperty(T myPayload)
        {
            return myPayload.getProperty();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SecondPayload<T> where T: IGetProperty
    {
        public string getProperty(T myPayload)
        {
            return myPayload.getProperty();
        }
    }
```

Two Questions: How would I then differentiate between the strings 1 and 2 based off the different classes and how would I call it from **MyFunction**?

```
private void MyFunction(T myPayload)
{
    string test = myPayload.getProperty(); // compile error
}
```

Comment: "Is there a way I can call the getProperty method from the parameter myPayload succintly?" - no,  C# does not support Structural Typing or Duck Typing - only **nominative typing** - you will need to introduce an interface.

Comment: You could either use an interface *nod*, or you can just probe for it via reflection *smell*

Comment: You don't need to use this: `if (typeof(T) == typeof(FirstPayload))` - you can use the `is` operator. You should add a `where T : class` constraint btw. You should never have to do an `Object` cast.

Comment: Alternatively, make the caller of `MyFunction` supply a `Func<T,String>` parameter.

Comment: Since there is a compile error: Did you add the generic type constraint? This is important.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface for that purpose

```cs
public interface IGetProperty
{
    string getProperty();
}
```

make the payload classes implement that interface

```cs
[DataContract]
public class FirstPayload : IGetProperty
{
    public string getProperty()
    {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

and then add a [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to the class containing `MyFunction` (would work with a type constraint on the method, too, of course, but the generic seems to be defined on your class).

```cs
class MyClass<T> where T : IGetProperty
{
    private void MyFunction(T myPayload)
    {
        string currLoad = myPayload.getProperty();
    }
}
```

Since the type parameter is constrained to the interface, you can use the methods of that interface (works with multiple interfaces, too).

#### Edit

Based on your comment it seems as if you are lacking some basics, so let me elaborate a bit.

You do not have to differentiate between two method calls. Basically what you do is to define a contract (the interface) that tells: I guarantee that this class (that implements the interface) will be accessible in a certain way (in this case your `getProperty` method). Everyone that owns an instance of whatever class that implements the interface knows that xe can call `getProperty()` and will get a `string` (disregarding the fact that exceptions may occur or the method may return `null`).

By constraining the type parameter (`T`) to your interface, we know that no matter what object is passed to the method, it will provide a `getProperty` method that you can access. What exact method is called is determined by what instance is passed to the method, but you do not have to care at all. The compiler will take care that no object is passed that does not implement the interface (since there is a type constraint), otherwise there will be a compile error at the line that is calling `MyFunction`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I had two questions left that I put in the edit.

I am curious how using this interface (I had my two calsses implement that interface) I would differentiate between different return values (ie "1" vs "2") and call this new function properly? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that does help a lot! Thank you.

I have one quick question to add onto your explanation. It used to be before the edit I could create a new instance such as
FirstPayload firstPayload = new FirstPayload();

Now how would I create this same logic with the generic logic added in as well in the edit?
FirstPayload firstPayload = new FirstPayload<T>;

Comment: @mikeg Ah, nahh you got me wrong. You do not have to add type parameters to the payload classes *at all*, this is just on the class that contains `MyFunction` :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow it works, thank you paul and have a good day/night

Comment: Glad I could help :)